# When system dialog show and then click theoderside of the dialog then show cuctom dialog but custom dialog show when user click then dont allow option

Tags: java, android

When system dialog show and then click theoderside of the dialog then show cuctom dialog but custom dialog show when user click then dont allow option. but when system dialog show to access the permission then user click oder side then then sytem dialog dissmiss and custome dialog show. I want to system dialog is not close in when user click oder side of screen.

```
   private final ActivityResultLauncher<String> cameraPermissionLauncher1 = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), result -> {
        if (!result) {
            Log.e(TAG, "on click Result=====> " + result);
            if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                // Show your dialog only once when the user denies the permission two times
                openAppInfoDialog();

            }
        }
    });if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ctx, Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES)) {
                        ImageUpload();
                        Log.e(TAG, "onPlusClicked: 1 ");
                        return;
                    }
                    cameraPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES);
                    return;
                }

            } else {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ctx, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    cameraPermissionLauncher1.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    return;
                }
            }
```